# Why do people recommend rooting a device before flashing a custom ROM?

Tags: rom-flashing

If rooting isn't required to flash a new ROM (unlocking your bootloader is), why do many people recommend rooting your device before flashing it?

Comment: I think this one really depends on the device and procedures involved in installing a new ROM. For Nexus devices, there's really no point because you can just `fastboot oem unlock` the bootloader. Other devices, however, may force you to use tricks that require root in order to unlock the bootloader. However, I'm not 100% up to date on non-nexus ROM installing and such so I could be mistaken.

Comment: @dotVezz That's not a comment, but an answer, go ahead posting it as such :) Maybe a hint to custom recovery wouldn't hurt either, as that might require root permissions to be installed (and on most devices is the pre-condition to flashing custom ROMs).

Comment: @Izzy, I just posted it as a comment since I wasn't quite sure of the non-nexus procedures. But I'll go ahead and put a slightly expanded version of that as my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this one really depends on the device and procedures involved in installing a new ROM. For Nexus devices, there's really no point because you can just `fastboot oem unlock` the bootloader and install your new recovery with `fastboot flash recovery [file]`.

Other devices, however, may force you to use tricks that require root in order to unlock the bootloader. For example, in order to install a ROM on a device which doesn't support [fastboot](/questions/tagged/fastboot), you may need root in order to install a custom recovery.

Comment: I don't remember ever having used `fastboot`, but I have CWM on some of my devices. So while some certainly require flashing it via `fastboot`, there must be other means; but I'm not aware of any such method *not* involving root :) +1 from me :)